# htaccess can not remove index.php

Tags: .htaccess

I used this code to force www and remove `index.php`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(.*/)?(?:index\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

It works on centOS server. but not in Ubuntu 16.

It can force www, but it does not remove `index.php`.

Also I want to redirect `example.org` to `example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no good reason why it would *part* work on one OS and not the other. Except if previous (erroneous) redirects had been cached.

However, your directives are in the wrong order. The internal rewrites (front controller) needs to come after the canoncial redirects, otherwise it will never "force www" or "remove `index.php`" when requesting a "virtual URL".

For example:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(.*/)?(?:index\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2? [R=301,L]

# Front controller should be after canonical redirects
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

> also I want redirect example.org to example.com

Add the following before the above redirects:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.